# Android webview not opening sdcard path starting with special character

Tags: android, android-webview, special-characters

In android, i am trying to open an html file from sdcard path to show it in web view . As my path starts with some special character( eg. sdcard/11/#directoryName/index.html), it is not opening that html file . can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any exception ? can show us the code as well as logcat ?

Comment: E/Web Console(26778): Uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined at file:///storage/sdcard/11/#directoryName/index.html) I am getting this exception. And my code to open is webview.loadUrl("file:///storage/sdcard/11/#directoryName/index.html");

Comment: Please show the code also which you are using to read the file.

Comment: Try to use escape character instead: `#` => `%23`. Hence, `sdcard/11/%23directoryName/index.html`

Comment: i have edited my above comment.

Comment: post your code and log output.

Comment: I have already posted

Comment: @david Wasser can u please have a look at this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142467/progressdialog-in-tabhost-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character "#" is not a legal character in an URL path. The "#" character is used to reference an "anchor" within a document. Usually used like this:

```
http://my.host.com/path/to/url#part-of-document
```

You could try to URL-encode that character in the path so that it doesn't get interpreted as an anchor reference, like this:

```
file:///storage/sdcard/11/%23directoryName/index.html
```

but it may be that you will need to read the file yourself and pass the data to the WebView instead.

Comment: Thank you , so for all the special characters i should encode manually before loading url ?

Comment: Yes. Note that, in general, you should try not to have special characters in file names.

Comment: ok.Thank you.  where i can find the other replacing encoding for other special characters ? Like # , other special character may also can come as i could not avoid special characters in my case

Comment: Use an ASCII chart, like http://www.asciitable.com/ you want to use the hex code for the replacement character, as 2-digits, preceeded by `%` character. Or you could try to call `URLEncoder.encode()` on the whole path string.